# Index size 400%+ growth: Normal Solr instance vs SolrCloud

Tags: solr, lucene, solrcloud

I'm experimenting with different infrastructure approaches and I'm surprised to notice the following.

I've indexed 1.3M documents (all fields indexed, stored, and some shingle-analyzed) using DataImportHandler via sql query in **Solr4.4.**

**Approach1**: Single Solr instance

Indexing time: **~10 minutes**

Size of "index" folder: **1.6GB**

**Approach2:** SolrCloud with two index slices.

Indexing time: **~11 minutes**

Size of "index" folders: 1.6GB + 1.5GB = **3.1GB**

Each of index slice has around 0.65M documents adding to original total count which is expected.

**Approach3**:SolrCloud with two shards (1 leader + 1 replica)

Indexing time: **~30 minutes**

Size of "index" folders: Leader (4.6GB), replica (3.8GB) = **8.4GB** (expected this to be 1.6gb * 2, but it is ~1.6gb*5.25)

I've followed the [SolrCloud tutorial](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SolrCloud).

I realize that there's some meta-data (please correct me if I'm wrong) like term dictionary, etc. which has to exist in all the instances irrespective of slicing (partition) or sharding (replication).

However, approach 2 and 3 show drastic growth (**400%**) in the final index size.

Please could you provide insights.

Answer (score 1):

From the overall index size I suppose your documents are quite small. That is why the relative size of the terms dictionary is big - for that number of documents it's pretty similar, so you have it twice. Therefore 1.6 turns into 3.1Gb.

As for Approach 3 - are you sure that it's a clean test? Any chance you have included transaction log in the size? What happens if you optimize?
You can check what exactly adds to the size by checking the index files extensions.
See here:
https://lucene.apache.org/core/4_2_0/core/org/apache/lucene/codecs/lucene42/package-summary.html#file-names